# Apache ActiveMQ: What is TCP Port 64119 Used For?

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am running Apache ActiveMQ 5.5 on CentOS 5.5.

I have searched the ActiveMQ website, source code, configuration files, and I cannot find any reference to this port.  Yet, when I start the broker, this is one of three TCP ports listened to by the JVM.

Does anyone know what port 64119 is used for by Apache ActiveMQ?

Comment: Just a thought... Maybe it's not related to ActiveMQ i.e., debug listening port or JMX end-point? EDIT: Did You try to telnet it? Maybe it does send some meaningful helo message. At last resort You could always sniff packets with Wireshark.

Comment: Did telnet already, but not Wireshark.  Good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have tried with ActiveMQ 5.4.2 on Ubuntu. It listens on:

- `61616` - broker protocol
- `8161` - web admin
- `39271` - JMX remote port

Server is not listening on any other ports.

EDIT: I checked with 5.5.0 and also restarted the broker (both 5.4.2 and 5.5.0) several times. JMX port is always different, looks like it's being randomized. I bet your `64119` changes over time as well.

To make it clear, connect to ActiveMQ broker with `jvisualvm`, you should see an open connection from `jvisualvm` to ActiveMQ process on this port (I can see it with `lsof`).

Comment: Thanks for answering...I've updated my question with version info.  By the way, do you mean "broker" protocol instead of "broken"? :)

Comment: Actually I have been testing 5.5.0 as well in the meantime, see my edit. Thanks for pointing out *typo* BTW :-).

Comment: Right you are.  Restarting the broker opens a different port.